# Word order with "just" and "only" meaning "merely"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, word-order, sentence-starts

Marking a German student's test I have encountered the following problem:

> The relationship between the two adolescents is one-sided. Just the boy really feels something, the girl hates him.

Can *just* be used here? My gut feeling says it should be *only*, although both words can mean "merely" and do in this case.

Comment: Rather than the words, it is sentence that needs a little fixing. "It is just that the boy who really feels...".

Comment: Can you tell us what was the intended meaning of the sentence?

Comment: @Kris your version makes even less sense.

Comment: @Kris "It's just that the boy who really feels something" doesn't make any sense. At all.

Comment: Oh right: "It's just that it's the boy who really feels something" -- sure, oversight.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "*Just the boy really feels something, the girl hates him.*" has two problems.

The first, as Barrie says, is the comma splice between two independent clauses.

The second is the contradiction. **Both the girl and the boy feel something.** Presumably, however, the boy loves the girl but the girl hates the boy. **Hate** is a feeling.

Neither *only* nor *just* is appropriate here.

> **The relationship between the two adolescents is {unbalanced / unequal / antagonistic / incongruous / inconsonant}. The boy loves the girl, but she hates him.**

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the meaning intended here is ‘merely’. The writer seems to mean that the boy felt something and the girl didn’t. In that case, *only*, rather than *just*, makes the meaning clearer. However, a comma can’t join the two clauses. It needs replacing with *and* or the two clauses should be rewritten as two sentences: *Only the boy feels anything. The girl hates him.*